# An InvokeCommand is not called in shell extension dll of windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, shell

My shell extension codes work well below windows 7.
However,in Windows server 2008x64 or windows 7x64, an invoked command function is not called  when the number of Selected Files are over 16.

When the number of Selected Files are below 17, everything is ok;
Calling Sequence : `QueryContextMenu -> Initialize -> GetCommandString -> InvokeCommand`

However, when the number of Selected Files are over 16, InvokeCommand is not called;
Calling Sequence :

```
 Initialize(the returned value of DragQueryFile is 16) 
    -> QueryContextMenu
    -> GetCommandString(the returned value of DragQueryFile is 16) 
    -> Initialize(the returned value of DragQueryFile is the selected file count) 
    -> QueryContextMenu -> Initialize(the returned value of DragQueryFile is only one)
    -> not call InvokeCommand
```

.

What's wrong?
Please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! InvokeCommand gets never called when you return the wrong result in QueryContextMenu. Thats means you have to return the last item ID plus one (which would be the next command id)

That means, if for instance you have the method

```
public int QueryContextMenu(
        IntPtr hMenu,
        uint iMenu,
        uint idCmdFirst,
        uint idCmdLast,
        uint uFlags)
```

yout get idCmdFirst = 38080 as input param. Then you add 1 menuitem. idCmdFirst is incremented to 38081. If you add 5 items you have to increment it for each item.

at the end of this method you return following:

```
 return WinError.MAKE_HRESULT(WinError.SEVERITY_SUCCESS, 0, (idCmdActual - idCmdFirst) + 1);
```

this would be (38081 - 38080) +1.
Then InvokeCommand gets called!